# UMVUE of parameter $(1-\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, unbiased-estimator, optimal

suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be random sample of $N(0,\sigma^2)$. how can I calculate UMVUE of parameter $(1-\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$

Comment: I think you just need to plug in the UMVUE for $\sigma^2$

Comment: self-study tag, maybe?! Start from any unbiased estimator and apply the Rao-Blackwell theorem.

Comment: @DeepNorth That doesn't work; since $(1-\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$ is a convex function of $\sigma^2$, by Jensen's inequality if you use $(1-\hat{\sigma}^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$ to estimate $(1-\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}$, that will be biased as long as the variance of the estimator is nonzero. Clearly, then you can't have an UMVUE. (in short, the UMVUE property doesn't survive convex transformations; indeed, not usally any nonlinear transformation)

Comment: Are you sure this question has been quoted correctly?  For odd $n$, $(1-\sigma^2)^{-n/2}$ is defined only for $\sigma^2 \lt 1$!

Comment: @whuber: I agree with you that it seems unlikely to be the right expression. Even $(1-\sigma^2)^{n/2}$ is only defined for even $n$'s (in which case _I_ can provide the UMVUE)...

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for the correction--of course I meant to write "even" instead of "odd"!